# Is it possible to apply authentication only on one endpoint in a WCF service?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a WCF service project with several endpoints with no authentication. There are clients that use the endpoints, but the clients cannot be changed.

Now, I'd like to add a new endpoint with Windows Authentication. I managed to apply this on the entire project, but this breaks compatibility with the clients that use the other endpoints as they don't touch the Username/Password properties on the service entity.

Is it possible to apply this authentication method on the particular endpoint so that the other services in the project remain with no authentication or should I create a new WCF project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Authentication is enabled at IIS level for the specified ASP.NET application. So you'd better create a new WCF service hosted in a separate application in IIS for which you can enable Windows Authentication. In terms of routes, you could always have a reverse proxy (such as nginx or HAProxy) in front of your IIS in order to achieve the desired routes and so that they look to the end user as if they were the same application.